# MySQL using NOT IN for temp table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to be able to find rows in Category table with condition of `visible = 0` not in the query result from below:

```
SELECT c.id as cat_id, j.id
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc
ON pjc.category_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN job j
ON j.id = pjc.job_id
WHERE c.visible = 0
AND j.end_date > CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY c.id
```

Is there a way to use `NOT IN` to find this?

I tried below but this loops forever and crashes mysqld

```
SELECT c.id
FROM category c
WHERE c.id NOT IN
(SELECT c.id as cat_id, j.id
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc
ON pjc.category_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN job j
ON j.id = pjc.job_id
WHERE c.visible = 0
AND j.end_date > CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY c.id)
AND visible = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What don't you try using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.ID
FROM    category a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  c.id as cat_id
            FROM    category c
                    LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc
                        ON pjc.category_id = c.id
                    LEFT JOIN job j
                        ON j.id = pjc.job_id
            WHERE   c.visible = 0 AND 
                    j.end_date > CURRENT_DATE
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL AND
        a.visible = 0
```